# Python Tkinter scrollbar isn't showing up

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I read through a bunch of tkinter questions that were asked here and haven't been able to figure out how to get the scrollbar to show up. Any help would be much appreicated.

```
    self.resultsCanvas = Canvas(self, bg='white', height=300, width=300, relief=FLAT).grid(column=0, row=8)
    self.resultsCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollResults.set)
    self.scrollResults = Scrollbar(root, command=self.resultsCanvas.yview).grid(column=11, row=8, sticky='E')
    self.blankSpace03 = Label(self, text="  ").grid(column=1, row=9)
```

I get the following error message:

```
self.resultsCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollResults.set)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize and layout a Widget on the same line if you want to keep the reference. You have to put those on separate lines:

```
self.resultsCanvas = Canvas(self, bg='white', height=300, width=300, relief=FLAT)
self.resultsCanvas.grid(column=0, row=8)
self.scrollResults = Scrollbar(root, command=self.resultsCanvas.yview)
self.scrollResults.grid(column=11, row=8, sticky='E')
self.resultsCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollResults.set)
```

It's good to always use separate lines to avoid this kind of bug in the future.

Comment: Thanks Novel, I broke out the lines but now I'm getting a different error: 
self.resultsCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollResults.set)
AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'scrollResults'

Comment: Yes, you need to define the scrollResults before you use it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Oh man, I feel dumb.  So it was a matter of ordering the yscrollcommand after defining the scrollbar widget.  Thank you so much, just starting to learn python and this helped a great deal!     Now I have to figure out how to make the scroll bar appear next to and not below the canvas  :D